# How to create inline table elements in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

**Goal:** Display some text with a paired word-for-word translation directly underneath.  Text must wrap in window.  Must work in HTML5.  Solution should look like this:

[Screenshot](http://example.teadroid.com/home/screenshots/wraptable.png)

Reason for HTML5 is I want the page to be supported in jQuery and jQuery Mobile.  Solution doesn't have to use tables, I just want to display these word pairs above/below each other.

This is my first post here but already been soaking up the wisdom from stackoverflow for weeks.  What a great resource!  Looking forward to some smart replies.

> **Additional info:**
>
> I have done it for non-HTML5 by using inline tables, but as soon as
>   you put in an HTML5 identifying "!DOCTYPE html" tag, it breaks and
>   the browser treats the tables as block level elements.
>
> My solution for non-HTML5:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>hello</td></tr><tr><td>bonjour</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>folks</td></tr><tr><td>les gens</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>thank you</td></tr><tr><td>je vous remercie</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>for your</td></tr><tr><td>pour votre</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>helping me</td></tr><tr><td>aide-moi</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>solve</td></tr><tr><td>à résoudre</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>this</td></tr><tr><td>ce</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>intractable</td></tr><tr><td>problème</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>problem</td></tr><tr><td>insoluble</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>.</td></tr><tr><td>.</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>hello</td></tr><tr><td>bonjour</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>folks</td></tr><tr><td>les gens</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>thank you</td></tr><tr><td>je vous remercie</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>for your</td></tr><tr><td>pour votre</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>helping me</td></tr><tr><td>aide-moi</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>solve</td></tr><tr><td>à résoudre</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>this</td></tr><tr><td>ce</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>intractable</td></tr><tr><td>problème</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>problem</td></tr><tr><td>insoluble</td></tr></table>
<table border="1" style="display:inline"><tr><td>.</td></tr><tr><td>.</td></tr></table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: the link to your screenshot doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `display: inline-table`.

Otherwise, you have a `display: table-row` inside a `display: inline` and the browser generates an anonymous `display: table` block to hold the `<tr>`.

---

That said, what you have really doesn't look like a tabular data structure.

I suspect you would be better off with a single table then:

```
table { display: inline; }
tr { display: inline-table; }
```

… although I haven't tested that so I can't say what browser support would be like.

Comment: That's the ticket - thank you!  And so fast.  Gone for the following:<br>

`table { display: inline-table; }`
`tr { display: inline-table; }`<br>
`<table><tr><td><div>folks</div><div>les gens</div></td></tr></table>`
`<table><tr><td><div>folks</div><div>les gens</div></td></tr></table>`
<br>
By the way, it doesn't work in IE7 but I like the elegance of the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The most cross-browser way to do this is probably to remove the `style` attributes (it’s not practical to use them anyway—repeating the same settings again and again) and to use the following style sheet:

```
 table { float: left; margin-right: 0.25em;  margin-bottom: 0.25em; }
```

This works on all CSS-enabled browsers, even old versions of IE. Tune the margin values as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - works great, and I tested its compatibility with older versions of IE.  Equal top solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the tables are only two-dimensional, why not just use a styled list (`LI`)?

```
<ul><li>Item One</li><li>Item Two</li></ul>
```

Then change the style of the list:

```
ul, li {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;display:inline;margin-right:10px;}
li {border:1px solid #000000}
```

Comment: Sounds intriguing, how would I use LI?  can you give an e.g.?

Comment: Tried but didn't work.  Item Two was on the right of Item One, not below it.  Will be using other solution, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

i think this will works for you as you shown screenshot : http://jsfiddle.net/5Ak2g/